# Making sh script start multiple Tmux sessions

Tags: sh, tmux

I wanted to make an `sh` script to open multiple Tmux windows with different commands.

```
for d in */ ; do
    tmux new-session -d ${d}start.sh
done
```

As you can see, I wanted to get the start.sh from every directory and launch it into its own unique tmux session.

I have no idea where I went wrong, sorry for bothering.

Comment: A session is a group of windows. Do you really want a new *session* for each file, or just a new window in an existing session for each file?

Comment: a new session, sorry for my misuse of the term window

Comment: Then what's the problem? What you have *does* create a new session for each script. You just aren't *attaching* to any of the sessions.